# Change nav background on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the background of navigation section of my website after user scrolls a specific amount of pixels. I have tried the following javascript code but nothing seems to be working. Sharing the javascript below. I couldn't figure out what is wrong. The javascript seems to be working but stops once the if condition is encountered.

```
function setName () {
  myNav = document.getElementById('navigation');
}

window.onscroll = function () {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 350){
    myNav.classList.add('nav-colored');
  }
};

window.onload = setName;
```

Comment: did u assign fixed height for the main container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead of `document.body.scrollTop`.

...as `document.body.scrollTop` not works on Chrome, FireFox, Opera etc because

> *[Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera places the overflow at the  level, unless else is specified. Therefore, you have to use the **documentElement** property for these browsers](https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/11/document-body-scrolltop.html)*

...It only works on safari

So you have to write both for browser support.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function navScroll() {
  var myNav = document.getElementById('navigation');
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350 || document.body.scrollTop > 350) {
    myNav.classList.add('nav-colored');
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  navScroll();
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

#navigation {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#navigation.nav-colored {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation"></nav>
```